# Drupal6 Deployment: Developed on XAMPP, when online localhost is still the base path

Tags: deployment, drupal, drupal-6

I developed a Drupal site on XAMPP. I deployed it to an Apache webserver by uploading a zip file and .sql file of the database. However, the links on pages generated by Views 2 are still as they were on XAMPP - http://localhost, etc. (So instead of www.example.com, it's http://localhost). Where do I change this setting?

I looked in settings.php but that doesn't appear to be it. I changed the `$base_url` value, but that didn't do it.

**EDIT:** this only applies to links generated by Views 2.

**EDIT 2:** Upon further investigation: it's only one specific View having this issue.

**EDIT 3:** When looking at the View preview on the administration page, it doesn't have this problem. The problem only occurs on the live version.

Comment: mind to post that view (index.php?q=admin/build/views > export)?

Comment: hm - doesn't make things much clearer for me. sorry, i give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your recent edits (especially that the preview works correctly), this *sounds like one of your views is still using cached data* created before you deployed the site to your live environment.

Try clearing all Drupal caches, but *especially the views cache* at `admin/build/views/tools`.

Comment: I go back to it now, and the problem is already fixed. I suspect that is a result of my cache already being cleared. Thanks so much. You've answered so many of my questions haha.

Answer (score 0):

usually, you don't need to change anything when changing server - Drupal figures out it's install location and url by itself (by looking at server variables like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` - see http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc?annotate=1.206.2.12&pathrev=DRUPAL-6#l293). eg. when you install at `http://www.example.com` and request that page, it should set $base_url to `http://www.example.com` and rewrite the links accordingly. if it doesn't, check that

- you don't set `$base_url` to another value (like `localhost`). note that Drupal searches for settings.php not only in `sites/default`, but also in [other locations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites--default--default.settings.php/6)
- you use Drupal's link generation functions ([url](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/url/6), [l](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/6)) instead of putting hardcoded values (like `localhost/...`) in your themes or modules.

Comment: turns out it's only links generated by Views... but I still don't know how to change it